# Sort 2d Array by ascending order using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've tried a map and forEach loop and still can't get this to sort by alphabetical order. Not sure what I am missing here.

My array:

```
const filtData = [
  [
    {
      gameType: "Rowing",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Rowing",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Rowing",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      gameType: "Golf",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Golf",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Golf",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      gameType: "Soccer",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Soccer",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Soccer",
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      gameType: "Baseball",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Baseball",
    },
    {
      gameType: "Baseball",
    },
  ],
]
```

Js:

```
filtData.forEach(d => d.sort((a,b) => a.gameType - b.gameType))
console.log(filtData) /* <--fails  */

const sortedData = filtData.map((d) => d.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.gameType - b.gameType;
}));
console.log("sortedData", sortedData)/* <--fails  */
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eL510oq3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- You're sorting based on strings, not numbers, so use `String#localeCompare`
- No need to use `forEach` or `.map`, just `sort`

```js
const filtData = [ [ { gameType: "Rowing", }, { gameType: "Rowing", }, { gameType: "Rowing", }, ], [ { gameType: "Golf", }, { gameType: "Golf", }, { gameType: "Golf", }, ], [ { gameType: "Soccer", }, { gameType: "Soccer", }, { gameType: "Soccer", }, ], [ { gameType: "Baseball", }, { gameType: "Baseball", }, { gameType: "Baseball", }, ], ];

filtData.sort((a,b) => a[0].gameType.localeCompare(b[0].gameType))

console.log(filtData);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting Array Objects in ASC Order Method 1 :**

```
let arrayConcat = filtData.reduce((preValue, curValue) => {
return preValue.concat(curValue)
}, []);

let result = arrayConcat.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.gameType.localeCompare(b.gameType);
})

console.log(result);
```